# How to remove access point / hotspot in Ubuntu?

Tags: hot-spot, wireless-access-point

This questions was already asked before, but any solution I try can remove the hotspot.

The stranger thing is that when I restart the PC, Ubuntu connects automatically to the wi-fi created by the hotspot. And this network is the only one displayed in Wi-Fi Networks. If I desconnect to this netowrk, then the other ones are finally displayed.

1. I turned off the hotspot in the Wi-Fi settings.
2. I deleted this wi-fi network in Edit connections.
3. I've searched the wi-fi connection in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`, but it is not in this directory.

How can I definitely remove the hotspot?

Comment: Strange. Have you restart pc?

Comment: @K.Sopheak yes. I've restarted it many times.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your network connection has the same name as your SSID.

They are different things, the SSID is the name that appears in the menu when you connect and it is the name you chose for the connection. 
However, on the 'Edit connections' menu, the one that appears is the network connection name and  not the name you actually expected. 
So check if you don't have connections called like 'wired connection 2' or 'wired connection 4' (ubuntu gives it random names like that). 
If you have one of those that you don't know the provenience of then click on edit, and check if it has the SSID name of the network you want to get rid of. If you do find it, delete it.